# Looping over list to delete items - unexpected behavior

Tags: python, list, loops, del

A simplified scenario that's not working as expected. I'm hoping someone can point out why.

```
nums = [0, 0, 4, 0]
new_list = nums
for i in range(len(nums)):
  if nums[i] !=0:
    break
  del new_list[0]
new_list
```

I'm trying to remove preceding zeroes. I expect the above loop to delete the first element of the list *until it encounters a non-zero number*, then break. It's only deleting the first zero, even though my `del new_list[0]` statement is in the loop.

Expected output: [4, 0]
Actual output: [0, 4, 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment operator in python (as used in `new_list = nums`) does not create a new object but just assigns another name to the existing object. Any changes you make to `nums` will also affect `new_list`.

To create a new object, you can make a shallow copy instead:

```
new_list = nums.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks @Olli. I swear I tried this, but oh well... Turns out I was banging my head against a wall over something super simple.

Answer (score 1):

In python, assignment operator doesn't make you a new instance of your object, in your casenums. I suggest you to read about deep copy and shallow copy in python. As [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/) says

> In Python, Assignment statements do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. When we use = operator user thinks that this creates a new object; well, it doesn’t. It only creates a new variable that shares the reference of the original object. Sometimes a user wants to work with mutable objects, in order to do that user looks for a way to create “real copies” or “clones” of these objects. Or, sometimes a user wants copies that user can modify without automatically modifying the original at the same time, in order to do that we create copies of objects.

You can make a deep copy using the copy module.

```
import copy


nums = [0, 0, 4, 0]  
new_list = copy.deepcopy(nums) # using deepcopy for deepcopy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = [0, 0, 4, 0]
new_list = nums # this refer to nums and when you change new_list, nums changes
# do following to make a copy.
new_list = nums[::]
for i in range(len(nums)):
  if nums[i] !=0:
    break
  del new_list[0]
new_list
```

Output

```
[4, 0]
```

Comment: While its good to have comments, adding the explanation for the problem and the solution as plain text in the answer body makes it easier to see. And remember that code-only answers are discouraged. Please take some time to refresh [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, @Someprogrammerdude for the suggestion, I'll take care of that next time. also'll update the answer(or'll put a link to reference) in some time.

Comment: @shivankgtm The time you spent in replying to Someprogrammerdude would've been enough for you to put in a line of meaningful explanation or two. Why wait till next time?